# Cycle in target dependencies detected in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, nuget-package-restore

I got this error while building Android project built using Xamarin.forms.

This happened after I installed Xam.Plugin.Media package and I cannot put it back.

Can anyone please help me? Thank you in advance.

> Error: Error building target _XamarinAndroidBuildAarProguardConfigs:
>   Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.InvalidProjectFileException: Cycle in
>   target dependencies detected
>         at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Target.BuildOtherTargets (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] targetNames,
>   System.Action`1[T] missing_target, System.Boolean& executeOnErrors)
>   [0x00065] in
>   /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Engine/Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine/Target.cs:263
>
> ```
>   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Target.BuildDependencies (System.Boolean& executeOnErrors) [0x0003f] in
> ```
>
> /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Engine/Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine/Target.cs:211
>
> ```
>   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Target.BuildActual (System.String built_targets_key, System.Boolean& executeOnErrors) [0x00091] in
> ```
>
> /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Engine/Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine/Target.cs:177
>   (Transportesbr.Droid)

Below is the package information in Android project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="CarouselView.FormsPlugin" version="4.4.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Plugin.CurrentActivity" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Plugin.Permissions" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugin.Media" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugins.Forms.ImageCircle" version="1.8.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugins.Forms.RoundedBoxView" version="1.0.0.7" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Build.Download" version="0.4.5" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.4.247" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="XFControls" version="1.0.0.6" targetFramework="monoandroid71" developmentDependency="true" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Could you please try to downgrade the `Xamarin.Build.Download` package to version 0.4.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following steps and it worked.

1. Updated all packages including the Xam.plugin.media in Android
   project to update package.config.
2. Pushed code to GitHub. Of course, I had a generic .gitignore
       file and the package files were ignored from commit.
3. Pulled the code again on new location and reinstalled the packages.
           It got run again!

We could create a fresh project and replicate the code, but I had too many files on the project and using the Github was much quicker than creating a new one.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, I just tried it and it worked great! I should have tried it before.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade the package **Xamarin.Build.Download** from Version 0.4.6 to **0.4.5**

How to downgrade Nuget - https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2378153-how-do-i-downgrade-a-nuget-package-